# No suitable driver found (minecraft forge 1.17.1)

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, mysql-connector, minecraft-forge

I started modding minecraft with forge 1.17.1 two days ago. I'm trying to connect to a mysql database. First I thought I forgot to add the dependencies so I tried with `implementation files("./libs/mysql:mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar")` but it didn't change anything. Then I tried with `Class.forname("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` but I got a `ClassNotFoundException`.
I need help please.

Comment: Can you share the full stracktrace you are getting?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/k0ZpVxGt
Here is the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Forge uses the [Gradle Build System](https://gradle.org). You are able to declare dependencies with Gradle. In 99.9% of all cases, you should never include a local jar file.

**Please note: I don't know your use case, but connecting to a mysql database from a minecraft client doesn't sound like a great idea when concerning security.**

The mysql jdbc connector is available on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.26/jar).
Because Forge uses a really old gradle version, I assume you are using the Groovy DSL (when your build file is called build.gradle). There is also the Kotlin DSL (when your build file is called build.gradle.kts).

Groovy DSL:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // maybe you have more repositories here
}
dependencies {
    // maybe also more dependencies here
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.26'
}
```

Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // maybe you have more repositories here
}
dependencies {
    // maybe also more dependencies here
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.26")
}
```

More about dependencies in the [Gradle Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/core_dependency_management.html).

Comment: I tried that and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: You also need to shade the library. [View this gist](https://gist.github.com/Commoble/ddc75e819a690198c15d26564d139333) to see how to do that.